# Pass a list from get method (or from a view) to post method ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I apologize if the heading is not very clear.
So, what I want to do is following.
I have a model class called "Class" that contains a list of "Students". I have a view that shows a checklist of Students. From that checklist I want to pass the selected students back to controller, where I will update the Database and my class will have new students and the added students will have a new class.

Here is what I have done so far but now I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

These are my controller actions

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddStudents(int? id)
    {
        List<Student> students = (from std in db.Students
                                  where std.St_cl_fk_id == null select std).ToList();
        //ViewBag.students = students;

        return View("Add_Students",students);
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("AddStudents")]
    public ActionResult AddStudentsPost(int? id,List<Student> students)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var temp = id;
            Class @class = db.Classes.Find(id);
            foreach (var item in students)
            {
                if (Request.Form[item.St_id.ToString()] != null)
                {
                    @class.Students.Add(item);
                }
            }
            db.Entry(@class).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Classes");
        }
        return View("Add_Student");

    }
```

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<GMASchoolProject.Models.Student>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Add_Students";
 }


  <h4>Student List</h4>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Check Students
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table>
                        @foreach (var std in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="@std.St_id" value="@std.IsSelected" /></td>
                                <td>@Html.Label((string)std.St_name)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px,0,15px,0;">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Students" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}


<div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything else that I am doing wrong, I am a newbie in this area. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of binding the view to a list of students, bind the model to your Class object that has a list of students in it.  That way, when you submit (post), you are sending the whole Model object into the Controller.

Change your AddStudentsPost method to take in Class object and do your logic there.

Finally, change the name of the "Class" object to something else, such as, "Course". Class should be reserved for actual classes so not to cause confusion.

You aren't far off, so keep going

Comment: Hey @CoyMeeks thanks for your suggestions. They are very helpful and I am working on them now. And I figured out how to solve my problem following this technique. Thanks a million.

Comment: If you don't mind marking mine as answer, that would close this out.  Welcome to coding!